# Online regex preview tool

Tags: webapp-rec, regex

Is there any good regex webapps out there?

I'd like to be able to set which type of regex syntax is used, enter some text and a regex and get matches highlighted. Preferably with different colors so it's easy to detect what in the regex is causing the match.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- http://gskinner.com/RegExr/
- http://www.rubular.com/ (Ruby)
- http://regexpal.com/ (Nice and clean GUI)
- http://www.regex-tester.de/regex.html (PHP)
- http://www.debuggex.com (JavaScript and PCRE)

Comment: this answer makes me smile. +1

Comment: +1 for regexpal - using it for more than 6 years or so...

Comment: its hard to see for which of your given options people are now voting ...

Comment: strfriend.com is no more

Answer (score 4):

http://gskinner.com/RegExr is good.

Answer (score 1):

I use the [RegexTester](http://www.regextester.com/index2.html) to do this, the site is pretty simple and does just what you ask.

Answer (score 0):

I've always used [regexlib.com](http://regexlib.com/) (here is their [testing page](http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx), they even have a [silverlight engine](http://regexlib.com/RESilverlight.aspx) in there which is quite cool). They also have a great library of regexes that people have submitted.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>[reAnimator](http://osteele.com/tools/reanimator/)</strike> is a great regular expression visualizer. It helped me optimize some tricky regexes.

**Update**: Sorry, dead link. The closest thing I could find was [this FSM simulator](http://ivanzuzak.info/noam/webapps/fsm_simulator/).

Comment: Dead hyperlink :(

Answer (score 0):

http://www.debuggex.com/

Includes visualizer for the pipes and colored visualizer for the test text matches.

Comment: No need to down-vote carelessly. The accepted answer added the Debuggex link using the "Edit" function after my answer was made. If the earlier answers should not contain same links as the accepted answer then one should down-vote all of the earlier answers around here, right?